# how to replace user input text with something of programer choice

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I wanted to replace a particular word in a text input field with another. For example, if the user has typed jason in the text input field, on clicking the button it should be converted to james. Simple answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Usin an `array` and put on it all words which you replacing want, then `on blur` check if the value is in this `array`, when this array has this value will replaced with `James`. try this example, type `Jason or Marko`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var array = ["Jason", "Marko"];
  $('input').blur(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (array.includes($this.val())) $this.val("James");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that you can try. There are many ways to do this but this is one simple way. Copy and create a name.html file in any text editor and open the file in any browser to see the result :-) 
You can also use https://codepen.io to test this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to replace "JASON" with "JAMES".</p>

<p id="stackOverflow">JASON</p>

<button onclick="replaceFunc()">Replace</button>

<script>
function replaceFunc() {
    var str = document.getElementById("stackOverflow").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace("JSON", "JAMES");
    document.getElementById("stackOverflow").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```